# UICollectionView reuse cell background issue

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

i am using UICollectionview to present 4 button, the user should select 1 button.
I created  **custom subclass of uibutton** :

```
class CustomButton: UIButton {

    override var isSelected: Bool{
        didSet{
            backgroundColor =  isSelected ? Constants.Colors.selectedMenu: Constants.Colors.menuCell
        }
    }

}
```

**Custom cell class :**

```
class SymptomCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var optionButton1: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var optionButton2: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var optionButton3: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var optionButton4: UIButton!


    func configCell(options :  [String]){
        optionButton1.setTitle(options[0], for: .normal)
        optionButton2.setTitle(options[1], for: .normal)
        optionButton3.setTitle(options[2], for: .normal)
        optionButton4.setTitle(options[3], for: .normal)
    }

    @IBAction func clickAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
         sender.isSelected = sender.isSelected ? false : true
    }
}
```

I saw that for example if i select button and scroll few more cells then button in same index get different background color even if i didn't pressed it.

[image]

inside the cell class i tried using :

```
 override func prepareForReuse() {
        optionButton1.isSelected = false
        optionButton2.isSelected = false
       // ...
 }
```

but it will deselect all items each time. 
what can i do?

Comment: Are you sure it'll deselect all?

Comment: @LeangSocheat it will deselect all buttons when i will swipe to next cell

Comment: your gif looks like page view controller or scrollview..lolz.

Comment: may you push your hold code with this?

Comment: @LeangSocheat check it now please

Comment: "I saw that for example if i select button and scroll few more cells then button in same index get different background color even if i didn't pressed it. " Make clear your question. sorry what does it mean with your question. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any `UIView` inside of the `UICollectionViewCell` must be stateless between cell reuses, so, you definitely have to keep your `prepareForReuse` function.

However, the `UICollectionViewCell` itself is restoring its `isSelected` state when it is reused at `indexPath` which has been selected before.

So, the approach can be to select the cell together with the button.
In your cell there should be something like this:

```
protocol MyCellDelegate : NSObjectProtocol {
    func optionButton1DidToggle(in cell: UICollectionViewCell?)
}

class MyCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    var delegate : MyCellDelegate?

    @IBAction func clickAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        // you can assign delegate to your cell, the same as UICollectionViewDelegate, and forward here click callback to your delegate,
        delegate?.optionButton1DidToggle(in: self) 
        //.....
    }

    override var isSelected: Bool {
        didSet{
            optionButton1.isSelected = self.isSelected
        }
    }

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        optionButton1.isSelected = false
    }
}
```

And `MyCellDelegate` implementation:

```
public func optionButton1DidToggle(in cell: UICollectionViewCell?) {
    if !cell.optionButton1.isSelected {
        collectionView.selectItem(at: collectionView.indexPath(for: cell) animated:false scrollPosition:.centeredHorizontally)
    } else {
        collectionView.deselectItem(at: collectionView.indexPath(for: cell) animated:false)
    }
}
```

Comment: What if i have more then just 1 "optionButton" ?

Comment: You mean more than one button in a single cell? Then you need a model behind your `UICollectionViewDataSource`, where every model object will store the state of cell's buttons for each `indexPath`. And you will set the state to the buttons in `UICollectionViewDataSource `'s `collectionView(_ cellForItemAt: indexPath)` function.

Answer (score -1):

Try To use prepareForReuse at your custom cell and set backgroundColor = nil

```
override func prepareForReuse() {

    backgroundColor =  nil
    optionButton1.isSelected = false
}
```